# Vaadin-8 ComboBox click has no effect

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin, vaadin8

I have a `ComboBox` in my Vaadin 8 code. 
`allAtts` here is a `Set` of `Attendant`-s, and the field `theAtt` in there is of type `String`:

```
private ComboBox<Attendant> theCB = new ComboBox<Attendant>(null,allAtts);
theCB.setEmptySelectionAllowed(false);
Binder<SearchArgs> binder = new Binder<SearchArgs>(SearchArgs.class);
binder.setBean(sas);
binder.forField(theCB).bind("theAtt");
.. 
VerticalLayout vl = new VerticalLayout(theCB, rb, deleteBtn);
```

What's more - this exact flow of `theCB` is a copy-paste from another class i wrote, on the very same type `Attendant`.

The problem here is the drop-down click on `theCB` is not working. That is, clicking that little chevron-down icon on the ComboBox is producing no effect. What could this be!?

I tried removing the other items, `rb, deleteBtn` in `vl`. Still didn't work.

Nothing else happening to `theCB` anywhere else.

TIA.

**EDIT:** 
`theCB` is otherwise functional. typing in the field is allowed, brings the choices and returns the selection accurately.

**EDIT-2**
https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-combo-box/issues/680 is not the issue. nothing changing when i pass a non-null label value to the constructor. Besides, it's working fine with null label in that other place in the code.

**EDIT-3**
Attendant contains several fields, one of which is String `att`. 
`SearchArgs` composes `Attendant` in a its field `theAtt`. `Attendant.toString()` returns `att` only.

Once again - this exact same logic is working, as i'm typing these, in another part in the code.

Also note: i since also tried the following without success:

- binding `theCB` on a separate binder, i.e. declare a second binder on `sas` and use that one for binding `theCB`
- cloning the `Attendant` objects that go into `theCB` as data-provider.

Comment: What do "theAtt" & "allAtts" contain? Can you please provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org) which reproduces your problem? It' really hard to guess what the problem might be with the details provided so far

Comment: Be careful with versions here.  In your *edit-2* you are referring to a bug in the vaadin component, which is part of vaadin 10 - not 8.

Comment: *sas* , the bean you are using, what is? Can you add the pojo of that class aswell?