# How to remove the button in Vaadin 8 ComboBox?

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin, vaadin8

I'm looking to remove the little chevron to the right of the Vaadin `ComboBox` -- the one I marked with blue in the image:

[image]

I'm looking to remove it completely from one specific instance of the `ComboBox` and i don't need to make it appear again in some cases on that `ComboBox`.

The `ComboBox` should be otherwise functional the same way -- show options in dropdown as the user types, disallow null selection, etc.

How can this be done?

Comment: Going off the documentation, there does not appear to be an "easy way" of doing this exclusively with vaadin. I think you may have to either go deep into the vaadin code to write your own combo-box class that can exclude an arrow, or look for a different library. Documentation: https://vaadin.com/api/com.vaadin/vaadin-core/10.0.3/com/vaadin/flow/component/combobox/ComboBox.html

Comment: Note, this is about Vaadin8 combo box, the doc is here, https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.5.1/com/vaadin/ui/ComboBox.html but yes, there is no server side Java method for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily the button has class name in CSS, "v-filterselect-button". So I recommend to try following, add style name to your combobox, so that you can target the specific instance

```
combobox.addStyleName("my-combo")
```

And in your theme mixin in your theme SCSS file add following

```
.my-combo .v-filterselect-button {
  display: none;
}

.my-combo .v-filterselect-input {
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: anything for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467748/vaadin-8-combobox-click-has-no-effect - that's the reason-for-existence of this Q